# Why does getting my view's frame return the full screen, even tho the view has been run through the safeArea constraints?

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, safearealayoutguide

Before presenting my GameScene I apply the safeAreaLayoutGuide to the initial view screen *(code below is from GameViewController)*.

If at any point **before I call** `view.presentScene(scene)` I try to get the view's frame, I get back an empty set.

If however I get the frame, **after** presenting the scene, I get the rect for the full screen, even though the view does appear within the safeAreaLayoutGuide.

How can I get the view's safe adjusted screen coordinates? *I should note I am doing this so I can apply the proper constraints to my GameScene, as I can only find how to do it for UIView.*

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView?{
        let screenWidthInPoints = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let screenHeightInPoints = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        let imageView = UIView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor , constant: -0).isActive = true



        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: screenWidthInPoints,
        height: screenHeightInPoints))
        scene.backgroundColor = .black
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        view.presentScene(scene)
        var myRect = view.frame
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIScreen.main.bounds` represents the entire screen, not just the safe area. You will have to create a separate view constrained to safe area insets to get the proper safe area size. In your case, you already have an `imageView` placed within the safe area. Try printing out its size after adding the constraints and do it within a `DispatchQueue.main.async` to make sure that it gets called only after the current pass layout is complete.

```
    let imageView = UIView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor , constant: -0).isActive = true
    
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("imageView.frame: ", imageView.frame)
        
        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: imageView.frame.width,
                                           height: imageView.frame.height))
        scene.backgroundColor = .black
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

Comment: This is much closer, I get the proper dimensions.  However DispatchQueue.main.async  returns so much later, am going to have to find a way to delay the GameScene being presented till the Queue returns and pass the numbers.  No resolved yet, but the closest I have come so far

Comment: Your queue answer got me close.  Sometimes the width comes back as zero thought (and I do wait for the queued code to complete) so I'll have to make sure I check the width carefully.  Thank you